# How to use a JSON file from an Onine server like turbo360?

Tags: swift, swift4.2

> I am using a do catch scenario to try a JSONDecoder(), the only >problem is that I keep catching the error, but when I review my code I >can't see the error, maybe I need another set of eyes to help me out >of this one!

I placed my JSON file in a storage folder in turbo360, I've also tried gitHub, but neither is working, I believe.

```swift
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    final let url = URL(string: "https://storage.turbo360.co/portfolio-website-hxoc6m/actors")

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        downloadJson()
    }

    func downloadJson() {
        guard let downloadURL = url else { return }
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: downloadURL) { data, urlResponse, error in
            guard let data = data, error == nil, urlResponse != nil else {
                print("something is wrong")
                return
            }
            print("downloaded")
            print(downloadURL)
            do
            {
                    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                    let actors = try decoder.decode(Actors.self,  from: data)
                    print(actors)
            } catch {
                    print("Something wrong after downloaded")
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}
```

> I supposed to get: JSONDonloadingSwift4.Actors
>   as confirmation that my JSON file has been accessed and decoded

Comment: I think we need to see your `Actors` definition.

Comment: When handling errors print the error and not some hard coded string, use`print(error)`.  The error object contains valuable information about what is wrong and right now you are throwing the information away.

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON is invalid. You are missing an opening `"` on the last image URL. Fix that and as long as your `Actor` definition matches you should be good. [jsonlint](https://jsonlint.com) is very useful for checking JSON structure.